# Suppress map and reduce progress for Hive queries

Tags: hive

Is there an option to suppress the map and reduce progress for a hive query, i.e.

```
2013-04-07 19:21:05,538 Stage-1 map = 13%,  reduce = 4%, Cumulative CPU 28830.05 sec
2013-04-07 19:21:06,558 Stage-1 map = 13%,  reduce = 4%, Cumulative CPU 28830.05 sec
```

while keeping all other output, particularly the query itself with the `-v` option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
hive -S -v -e "select * from test;"
```

`S` is  for silent mode

`v` is for query display

`e` is for executing the query